# Is there a way to burn into a virtual CD-R instead of burning into a real one?

Tags: itunes, mp3, cd-burning

There is some `.m4b` files from the iTunes store that I bought, and from what I understand, these files cannot be converted into `.mp3`, unlike the `.m4a` files.

To put those files into another audio player that I have that can only support `mp3`, I need to convert it... and it looks a way to do it is to burn the `.m4b` into a CD-R, by first creating a playlist, and then burn the playlist into a CD-R, and there are up to 7 times that can be done.  Then, once the CD-R is made, then it can be ripped as an `.mp3`

But since I don't really need a CD-R version, so an extra CD-R will be wasted.  Is there a way to burn the `.m4b` onto some virtual CD-R and then rip it instead?  (for Snow Leopard or Lion).  But if it involves installing questionable shareware that might slow down the machine overall, it may be not as desirable -- so if it is shareware, it'd better be a reliable and trustworthy shareware.

(as a side note, the `.m4b` protection doesn't seem very strong... since anybody can just burn it and rip it, and then it is DRM free... the cost is only about 10 cents for CD-R, for about 16 songs... so the use of `.m4b` as a protection together with the ability to burn it onto a CD-R is somewhat strange to me)

**Update:** it seems like we can use a CD-RW and write it and erase it... and there won't be any wasted CD-R...  the only thing is I don't know how many times they can be erased...

Comment: Thank the recording industry for making all of their consumers out to be thieves. I know exactly what you want to accomplish, but I've never seen a virtual optical drive software ala. Alcohol 52%/120% or Daemon Tools.

Comment: CD-RWs can be written to > 1000 times, typically.

Answer (score 2):

While you can write data to a `.iso` file in Disk Utility, I don't believe there's any way to do so with the burning functionality built in to iTunes.

You could however get a program like [Virtual CD-RW](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33355/virtual-cd-rw), which presents itself as a CD-RW drive to the OS, which iTunes could then burn to. The reviews for that program don't look great, so I'd suggest getting the demo version and seeing if it works for you before paying any money.

Roxio's [Toast Titanium](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html) may include similar functionality, but I couldn't find any definite confirmation of that on their site.

Comment: please also see update in the question about using CD-RW

Comment: @太極者無極而生 He was talking about [a program](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33355/virtual-cd-rw), not a physical CD. By the way, robmathers, I just tried that program for this exact task, and it worked absolutely splendidly on Yosemite. Beautiful. Thank you so much for this. 太極者無極而生, you should accept this answer, IMO. [That program](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33355/virtual-cd-rw) does **exactly** what you asked for.